# Spring-Security for Android

Tags: android, spring, jpa, spring-security

I'm writing application for android.
 
I have used `SpringBoot`, `SpringData JPA` and `Retrofit` to connect Android with TomCat. I'm trying to do authentication in my Android Aplication with `Spring Security`.
My requirement is that, once the users are authenticated they will be sent token to use for subsequent calls.
Could you please provide me and example what I have to do this.

Comment: Once the user is authenticated via Spring_Security, it will give you a session_id called as JSESSIONID. Save it in your android application and for any further requests which you make to the server, just add this in the request, and the user will be recognized by Spring-security. You don't need any complex libraries or anything for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understand from your question is

1. How will you build a spring based server application that employs token based security?

Ans. - For this you need to create server application with Oauth2 security using JWT tokens. You can refer these tutorials for the same.
http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-jwt
Apart from this you can find many other sample tutorials on google and samples on github.
Use this link for basic reference.
http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html

2. How you will handle token based security at Android based UI application.

Ans. You can refer following tutorial for the same.
http://www.baeldung.com/retrofit

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE - 19-11-2019**

If you do not need/want oauth2 server for authentication, you can use pure filter based spring security also. Ref - https://medium.com/@hantsy/protect-rest-apis-with-spring-security-and-jwt-5fbc90305cc5

It shows how you can use jwt token based security using spring boot.